# Suppress checkstyle for lombok's val using SuppressionXpathFilter

Tags: java, lombok, checkstyle

I am using lombok's `val` to specify the final variables in my code. The checkstyle rule for FinalLocalVariable reports any `val` variable as non-final. I am trying to write a custom suppress.xml to suppress this check for any `val` field. Currently, my suppression.xml looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE suppressions PUBLIC
    "-//Checkstyle//DTD SuppressionXpathFilter Experimental Configuration 1.2//EN"
    "https://checkstyle.org/dtds/suppressions_1_2_xpath_experimental.dtd">
 <suppressions>
<suppress-xpath 
        checks="FinalLocalVariable" query="//VARIABLE_DEF[./TYPE/IDENT[@text='val']]"/
</suppressions>
```

I have generated the AST tree for the class that has the `val` fields, here is the part where `val` is declared

```
`--SLIST -> { [32:96]
    |       |--VARIABLE_DEF -> VARIABLE_DEF [33:4]
    |       |   |--MODIFIERS -> MODIFIERS [33:4]
    |       |   |--TYPE -> TYPE [33:4]
    |       |   |   `--IDENT -> val [33:4]
```

My idea was to specify that any variable definition of identity `val` should be ignored for this exact check. I have read the checkstyle's documentation for SuppressionXpathFilter and I cannot find what my issue is as the checkstyle keeps reporting that the variable should be declared final. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to address the IDENT child node of the VARIABLE_DEF with the suppression query:

```
query="//VARIABLE_DEF[./TYPE/IDENT[@text='val']]/IDENT"
```

For the following source code:

```java
class C {
    void m() {
        val a = 3;
    }
}
```

with the following checkstyle config:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC
        "-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Check Configuration 1.3//EN"
        "http://www.puppycrawl.com/dtds/configuration_1_3.dtd">
<module name="Checker">
    <property name="fileExtensions" value="java"/>
    <module name="TreeWalker">
        <module name="SuppressionXpathFilter">
            <property name="file" value="suppressions-check.xml"/>
        </module>
        <module name="FinalLocalVariable"/>
    </module>
</module>
```

using this suppression filter file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE suppressions PUBLIC
        "-//Checkstyle//DTD SuppressionXpathFilter Experimental Configuration 1.2//EN"
        "https://checkstyle.org/dtds/suppressions_1_2_xpath_experimental.dtd">
<suppressions>
    <suppress-xpath checks="FinalLocalVariable" query="//VARIABLE_DEF[./TYPE/IDENT[@text='val']]/IDENT"/>
</suppressions>
```

Checkstyle won't report any error.

Comment: Unfortunately, it still doesn't work and reports `val` as a violation of the final local variable check. I had to disable this check for now. Do you think there is something else I could try?

Comment: I've included a more detailed configuration in the answer. Could you specify your source code using the val keyword for debugging?